# How to find out the last task assigned and its time allowed using appscript & google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I get data like this, wherein tasks are being assigned to employees on a daily basis mostly 2 - 3 tasks every day.

[image]

The timestamp column shows when was the last task allotted.

What I need is a summary of the following details:

1. How many employees were assigned the tasks and their details as in their Ids and Names?
2. What was the last task assigned to them based on the timestamp.
3. What is the time allowed as per the standards

Only current date's data should show up there.

Something like this:

[image]

Time allowed should come from the time allowed standard sheet.
[image]

Please help me in knowing how to do it with appscript...
Thanks in advance

Comment: That's essentially a pivot table.  You can do it with script or you can use Google Sheets Pivot Table Tool

Comment: Please help me do it with appscript

Comment: Why can't you do it?

Comment: I tried but it won't work

Comment: Keep trying until it does work.

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Do you have a code you are working on?

Comment: It is not allowing me to paste the whole code hereCant paste the whole code here...Can I get your email Id so that i can show u

Comment: You can edit your question, add your code there.